# How to call Oracle Function from Java program

Tags: java, oracle, function, jdbc

**How to call Oracle Function from Java program...** 
I'm trying to access a function in my db, but i'm not able to do it. I'm doing it in same way as accessing oracle stored procedure.

```
String packageCallStmt = "{? = call XTRA_TSF_CRE_SQL.XTRA_TSF_CRE(?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }";
    try{

        conn = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
        System.out.println("Inside TransferCreationDAO - Before function call");
        OracleCallableStatement oracleCallableStmt = (OracleCallableStatement) conn.prepareCall(packageCallStmt);
        oracleCallableStmt.setInt(2, src_id);   
        oracleCallableStmt.setInt(3, dest_id);
        oracleCallableStmt.setString(4, refNo);
        oracleCallableStmt.setString(5, item);
        oracleCallableStmt.setInt(6, qty);
        oracleCallableStmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
        oracleCallableStmt.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Inside TransferCreationDAO - After function call");
        tcr.setTsf_No(((OracleCallableStatement) oracleCallableStmt).getString(1));
        System.out.println("Inside TransferCreationDAO - Tsf Number:"+tcr.getTsf_No());

    }
```

Comment: Package Name -> XTRA_TSF_CRE_SQL
Function Name -> XTRA_TSF_CRE
Getting an exception - PLS-00302: component 'XTRA_TSF_CRE' must be declared

Comment: your problem is "PLS-00302"... it's not from your java code it's from Oracle DB

Comment: Are you able to execute this function in DB directly - XTRA_TSF_CRE_SQL.XTRA_TSF_CRE? Secondly, check whether the number of input and output parameters including return value is matching. Can you please share the function signature here?

Answer (score 0):

- make sure your XTRA_TSF_CRE_SQL schema has a function name as XTRA_TSF_CRE_SQL.
- is you User (which use by java program) has privilege to access this function.
- **You can get that error if you have an object with the same name as the schema.**

may be it will solve your problem .